# Django Rest Framework custom throttling classes not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am having issues with setting up `custom throttling` using the `django-restframework` for `django`.
I made the following `views.py` class which contains a view with this custom throttle:

```py
from .custom_throttles import *

@api_view(('GET',))
@throttle_classes([LowLevelThrottle])
def home_stats(request):
  token = request.data['token']

  if token == os.environ['api_token']:
    content = {
      'users' : len(Profile.objects.all()),
      'posts' : len(Post.objects.all()),
      'reactions' : len(PostReaction.objects.all())
    }
  
    return Response(json.dumps(content), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
  else:
    content = {
      'error' : 'invalid token'
    }
    
    return Response(json.dumps(content), status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

This custom throttle is imported from `custom_throttles.py` which looks as following:

```py
from rest_framework import throttling

class LowLevelThrottle(throttling.AnonRateThrottle):
  scope = 'll'
```

And last but not least, this is how I have some settings in my `settings.py` file setup:

```py
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'django_project.custom_throttles.LowLevelThrottle'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'll': '1/sec',
    }
}
```

I also have the following logs I can provide clearly showing how multiple requests were made within this 1 second time frame.

```py
[24/Aug/2022 07:43:14] "GET /homestats HTTP/1.1" 200 51
[24/Aug/2022 07:43:23] "GET /homestats HTTP/1.1" 200 51
[24/Aug/2022 07:43:23] "GET /homestats HTTP/1.1" 200 51
[24/Aug/2022 07:43:23] "GET /homestats HTTP/1.1" 200 51
[24/Aug/2022 07:43:24] "GET /homestats HTTP/1.1" 200 51
[24/Aug/2022 07:43:24] "GET /homestats HTTP/1.1" 200 51
[24/Aug/2022 07:43:24] "GET /homestats HTTP/1.1" 200 51
[24/Aug/2022 07:43:24] "GET /homestats HTTP/1.1" 200 51
[24/Aug/2022 07:43:24] "GET /homestats HTTP/1.1" 200 51
[24/Aug/2022 07:43:25] "GET /homestats HTTP/1.1" 200 51
[24/Aug/2022 07:43:25] "GET /homestats HTTP/1.1" 200 51
[24/Aug/2022 07:43:25] "GET /homestats HTTP/1.1" 200 51
```

If you have anymore questions feel free to ask them!

Comment: You are making GET requests, and in your allow_request method of LowLevelThrottle you are allowing all GET requests to pass

Comment: @TrueGopnik yep, and I never noticed... Thank you!

Comment: However, even when removing the entire "def allow_request(self, request, view):" bit it is still not working.

Comment: In SimpleRateThrottle docstring is wtirren "Period should be one of: ('s', 'sec', 'm', 'min', 'h', 'hour', 'd', 'day')", maybe try changing 1/second to 1/sec or 1/s?

Comment: @TrueGopnik still allows me to do more requests per second.

Comment: I have created new project with your view, throttle class and it's working correctly, what version of django-rest-framework have you installed? Python version?

Comment: Aren't you logged in when making these requests?

Comment: djangi-rest-framework: 3.13.1, python 3.8.12 and I use custom token authentication that doesn't authenticate users in the back end.

Comment: Yep, replicated this issue and removing CACHES seems to fix this issue in my project, so perhaps MemcachedCache is not working (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by user [TrueGopnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16494437/truegopnik) I removed the

```py
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

from the `settings.py` file.